# EntityFramework-Plus Query Filter - Child/Relational entity not loading

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-plus

I am using Query Filter By Instance on user-id.

Application's entity structure -> one college has many students.

Applied user-id filter on both college and it's student.

When i access data by two user simultaneously, first user get it's college and all it's student but when request comes from second user only college loading failed two load it's student, both users has it's college and associated child students.

This issue occurs only when i query college by id(this.dbContext.College.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == collegeId)) not for get all(this.dbContext.College).

Comment: Are you using LazyLoading to load student? There is some limitation with this library for EF6 + Lazy Loading

Comment: Yes, using lazy loading for student. Actually it work for first user all requests and failed for second user all requests.                                                                It's issue of EntitiFramework-Plus? any solution or i can refer any other filter library?

Comment: For temporary solution - i was loading all college and student before applying instance filter on it, than it works but causes performance issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

Filtering using instance context + Lazy Loading is a limitation for this library. There is currently no workaround that I may recommend you.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [EntityFramework.DynamicFilters](http://entityframework-dynamicfilters.net/)

This library will work better for your situation and can handle this kind of scenario correctly.